# How to hide all child pages with post_query?

Tags: php, loop, pages, page-template, child-pages

i have a page template as start page(home.php). i use a 2 columns grid to display all pages on that home.php with title and excerpt. unfortunately also my child pages are shown and i can't figure out how to hide them.

I am not trying to make a list menue or something, its more like a gallery of my pages.

for now i use "query_posts('post_type=page' .$parent);" with the mentioned result. i tried to use an array as well, but this will give me posts instead of pages (fr reasons i havnt understood yet). 
What am i missing to hide all child pages and only display the parent pages?
Any help?
Thanks in advance!
Dan

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter in WP_Query called post_parent. Normally this refers to the ID of the post's parent, but since its an integer field, pages without a parent have in essence a post_parent of 0.

So, to get all pages that are not child pages of another page, you could use

```
query_posts( 'post_type=page&post_parent=0' );
```

or, in array syntax that would be

```
query_posts( array( 
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => 0 ) );
```

Comment: o.k. now i am speechless since i was sure i had tried this and it didn't worked, but i obviously must have done something wrong. your solution works like a charme. Thanks a thousand times!!! the only issue i have now is that the pages are displayed correct, but the order is not the way i used in the main navigation (same pages). i tried to order by count but didnt get this work.. any idea? thans again!

Comment: Try `'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC'` - that will order the pages by the menu order set in the Page Attributes box. If you're talking about the order you've given them is a custom nav menu, though, there's no easy way to get at that order without a lot of joins and filters...